# import nested dictionary in pandas (from yaml)

Tags: pandas, yaml

There are several questions like this, but the problem is that I have a dictionary of dictionary of ... and not a list of dictionary

I am importing a yaml file like

```
category1:
  region1:
    effect1:
       up: 10
       down: 20
    effect2:
       up: 30
       down: 50
    ...
  region2:
    effect1:
     up: 30
     down: 40
  ...
  region3:
  ...
category2:
  region1:
  ...
```

when importing with `yaml.load` I get one single big dictionary like

```
{'category':
     {'region1':
          {'effect1':
               {'up': 10, 'down': 20},
           ...
```

I can I import this in pandas? I want to get a flat table with multiindex:

```
                                 up  down 
category1   region1    effect1   10    20
category1   region1    effect2   30    50
...
category1   region2    effect1   30    40
...
```

I would like a general solution, since for example I have some data that are missing the `region` layer.

Comment: I've never worked with YAML before, so my initial reaction is to take this YAML file and make it into something that pandas works well with from the get go. Example being that you make this data format into a list of lists, or a dictionary, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `json_normalize` if you have a dict to generate a dataframe, then split and expand the columns i.e

```
di = {'category1': {'region1': {'effect1': {'up': 10, 'down': 20},'effect2': {'up': 12, 'down': 22}}},
  'category2':{'region2': {'effect1': {'up': 10, 'down': 20},'effect2': {'up': 12, 'down': 22}}}}

k = pd.io.json.json_normalize(di)

    #category1.region1.effect1.down  category1.region1.effect1.up  category1.region1.effect2.down  category1.region1.effect2.up ...
#0                              20                            10                               22                            12 ... 

k.columns = k.columns.str.split('.', expand=True)
# Transpose and unstack the dataframe for getting the actual dataframe 
main_df = k.T.unstack()[0]
```

Output:

```
                           down  up
category1 region1 effect1    20  10
                  effect2    22  12
category2 region2 effect1    20  10
                  effect2    22  12
```

Or an equivalent :

```
k = pd.io.json.json_normalize(di).T
k.index = k.index.str.split('.',expand=True)
mdf = k.unstack()[0]
```

Comment: thank! I used `json_normalize` but I was stucked with the final step of splitting the columns! Why isn't automatic?

Comment: Ruggero Turra I really dont know why it wasn't automatic but it might happen sometime sooner in future developments.